# Maximum current, maximum voltage

Tags: thevenin, source

Given that 0 <= R <= ∞  in the circuit shown, consider these two observations:

> Observation 1: When \$R = 2\Omega\$ then \$v_R = 4V\$ and \$i_R = 2A\$.
>
> Observation 2: When \$R = 6\Omega\$ then \$v_R = 6V\$ and \$i_R = 1A\$.

[image: Observation Schematic]

1. The maximum value of \$i_R\$ and the value of R that causes \$i_R\$ to be maximal.

   I don't understand how to calculate the maximum value of \$i_R\$ and R. Could someone give me some pointers and hints to get me on the right track to solve this problem? I was thinking of calculating the voltage of open circuit and short circuit current using source transformation.
2. The maximum value of \$v_R\$ and the value of R that causes \$v_R\$ to be maximal.

   Could somebody help me explain how to solve this problem?
3. The maximum value of \$P_R = i_R v_R\$ and the value of R that causes \$P_R\$ to be maximal.

   Again, I don't understand what I'm supposed to do in this problem. If you can lead me to the right direction that would be great. I don't need you to solve the problem for me.

*([Original image of observation text.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYtWc.png))*

Answer (score 2):

From the two statements you can see that a change in voltage caused a current change of 1A.  This means that if we consider the Thevenin equivalent of the circuit that it has an output resistance of 2V/1A = 2 ohm.  Also we can see that if we chafe R to infinity the voltage will rise to 8V (the 6V we had in statement 2plus an additional 2V by reducing the current by 1A from 1A to 0A).  The Thevenin equivalent is therefor an 8V source with a 2Ohm series resistor.

The maximum current for question (a) will be 4A with R = 0.

The maximum voltage for question (b) will be 8V with R = infinity

The values of the 24 ohm and the 6 ohm in the source are inconsistent with the measurements - that would have a Thevenin equivalent of a 24 ohm in parallel with 6 ohm which is 24/5 = 4.8 ohm.

kevin